# Exim dnslookup driver - router dnslookup: cannot find router driver "dnslookup

Tags: linux, exim

I am setting up Exim for the first time on a test server (compiled from source). I am following the HowTo at [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/OLD/exim.txt). I have editted the configuration file as given in the link. I then, run this command - `/usr/sbin/sendmail -bd -q15m` .

I get an error that says ***"Exim configuration error in line 516 of /etc/exim/exim.conf:
  router dnslookup: cannot find router driver "dnslookup""*** My Exim config file can be found here - [Exim Config File](http://pastebin.com/3NM1Pq1E)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have built exim without the dnslookup router.  You can use the `-bV` option to view how exim was built:

```
OVZ-CentOS58[root@ivwm51 ~]# exim -bV | grep Routers
Routers: accept dnslookup ipliteral manualroute queryprogram redirect
```

In your case, you will not see the word "dnslookup" there.  Remove the grep part to see the entire output.

To fix this, change your Local/Makefile by making sure this is enabled and not commented out:

```
ROUTER_DNSLOOKUP=yes
```

Then rebuild and install your exim, and it should be functional.